# Get distances within polygons based on a line

Tags: postgis, polygon

Setup:

- Country regions are stored as Polygons in postgres/postgis (Region:id:region_poly)
- Cross-country routes are stored as Lines in a different table (Route:id:route_line)

Problem:

- Given a Line (route_line), how can I pull the length of the line in each polygon (region_poly) with a single query

Example:

- Given Polygon A, B, and C, and a line X that crosses all three of these polygons, I'd like to get something like: {"A": 10km, "B": "160km", "C": 16km}

I think I have to use the ST_Intersection with ST_Length, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. (I'm still new to the gis stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you basically just need an intersection of the linestrings and polygons, get the length with st_length and use the sum function with a group by on the unique polygon name or id. I am not sure what your columns are exactly so I will give you a generic query that you should be able to plug and play

```
select sum(st_length(st_intersection(c.geom,l.geom))) as length_of_route,
 c.region_id, c.other_column,l.other_column
from country_regions c join cross_country_routes l 
  on st_intersects(c.geom,l.geom)
group by region_id,c.other_column,l.other_column
```

Comment: Depending on the coordinate system of the source data, you might have to wrap an ST_Transform(line.geom) to get something in meaningful units...

Comment: ...or, to get maximum precision, cast the intersection geometry (from EPSG:4326) to *geography* type to get measurements in meter on spheroid.

Comment: Thank you all guys, that was extremely helpful! I ended up tweaking 
ziggy's function a bit, then recasting it to geography, dividing by a 1000 and I got the exact results I needed.